# In carbon-components-svelte TreeView: how to change cursor to pointer on hover of a children?

Tags: svelte, carbon-design-system, carbon-components-svelte

The examples from https://carbon-components-svelte.onrender.com/components/TreeView can't do that, but the left tree in the document itself can.

Wondering how is that achieved?

Comment: Also asked in github issues: https://github.com/carbon-design-system/carbon-components-svelte/issues/1402

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "tree" on the left is the `SideNav` which is part of the [UI shell](https://carbon-components-svelte.onrender.com/components/UIShell). It just has that cursor change as part of its default styling.

If you want to override the style of the tree view, you just have to add some additional CSS.

```css
/* Within a component :global(...) needs to be used */
.bx--tree-node  {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

[REPL example](https://svelte.dev/repl/c778ed8f59f64dcfba3f2f9270594c4a?version=3.49.0)

Comment: That css works for `TreeView`.

Comment: So `UI shell` is a better option than `TreeView` for the side navigation?

Comment: Yes, that is what it is for.