# In carbon-components-svelte TreeView: how to share the tree on multiple route pages?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, carbon-design-system, carbon-components-svelte

I added the TreeView in `__layout.svelte`, and `on:select` I use svelte's `goto()` to jump to a path defined for the selected id.

But there are several **issues:**

- If I pass the url of a sub page on the tree, the left tree can't be selected correctly, it always select the default one.
- Similarly, If I click a link, the left tree can't be selected correctly.

I saw the left tree from [document](https://carbon-components-svelte.onrender.com/components/TreeView) works well.
How is that done?

**Questions:**

- So, how to change / init the `activeId` properly, when the id is not selected by click items in the tree?
- Is there a better way to share the tree among multiple route pages?

Comment: Also asked in github issues: https://github.com/carbon-design-system/carbon-components-svelte/issues/1403

Comment: Please do not create spam like that in the Github issues.

Comment: @H.B. OK, I've closed the github issue with link to this question, I was not sure where to ask the question (github or SO).

Comment: If you want to know how the navigation of the docs is implemented, you can [read its code](https://github.com/carbon-design-system/carbon-components-svelte/blob/f8e400f2edd971f41dacfbc21bfff4ee059e5163/docs/src/pages/_layout.svelte#L100).

Comment: @H.B. So, use `SideNav` instead of `TreeView` as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/73000993, there won't be such issue any more ? Let me try.

Comment: Cool, let me rewrite my code with the link.

Comment: You still need to use it correctly, and the docs do not use SvelteKit and its router, but [`@sveltech/routify`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sveltech/routify).

Comment: @H.B. Just replaced `<TreeView>` with `<SideNav>`, make the `<slot>` inside `<Content>`, works very well.

Comment: You can post that as an answer

Comment: @H.B. Answer added.

Answer (score 0):

*(As mentioned in comment by @H.B , using `<SideNav>` from [UIShell](https://carbon-components-svelte.onrender.com/components/UIShell) instead of `<TreeView>` solved the problem.)*

You may refer to this [example](https://carbon-components-svelte.onrender.com/components/UIShell#header-with-side-navigation) from the document.

Here is part of my code in `__layout.svelte`:

```
<script>
  import "../../app.css";
  import "carbon-components-svelte/css/all.css";

  import {
    SideNav,
    SideNavItems,
    SideNavMenu,
    SideNavMenuItem,
    SideNavLink,
    SideNavDivider,
    Content,
    Grid,
    Row,
    Column,
  } from "carbon-components-svelte";

  let isSideNavOpen = true;
</script>

<SideNav bind:isOpen={isSideNavOpen}>
  <SideNavItems>
    <SideNavLink href="/home" text="Home"/>
    <SideNavLink href="/home/content" text="Contents"/>
    <SideNavMenu text="Menu">
      <SideNavMenuItem href="/home" text="Home 1"/>
      <SideNavMenuItem href="/home" text="Home 2"/>
    </SideNavMenu>
    <SideNavDivider/>
    <SideNavLink href="/" text="Index"/>
  </SideNavItems>
</SideNav>

<Content>
  <Grid>
    <Row>
      <Column>
        <slot></slot>
      </Column>
    </Row>
  </Grid>
</Content>
```

**Tips:**

- Should add `<slot>` inside `<Content>`, otherwise the side nav might overlap part of the slot.

**BTW**, I'm using this in `svelte-kit`.

Comment: Note that the UI shell should include a `Header` which needs to bind `isSideNavOpen`: `<Header ... bind:isSideNavOpen>`. On small screens, e.g. mobile phones, the `SideNav` will be hidden automatically and the header will show a button which opens is. You could of course implement your own button that fulfills this role on small screens.

Comment: @H.B. Seems the `<Header>` is for `<HeaderNav>`, and optional for `<SideNav>`, I'm not sure. But, if I wrap `<SideNav>` inside `<Header>`, the side bar overlap the content part. I'll check how to hide/show side nav later, for now I always show it (`let isSideNavOpen = true`).

Comment: BTW, I have another top level `__layout.svelte`, if I add `<Header>` in the 2nd level `__layout.svelte`, seems it will also hide the non-slot part of the parent `__layout.svelte`.

Comment: `<HeaderNav>` is optional and only for the navigation at the top. `<Header>` should appear before `<SideNav>` at the same level, see the [example in the documentation](https://carbon-components-svelte.onrender.com/components/UIShell#header-with-side-navigation).

Comment: There seems to be some issue, I'll try more on this later, and update here if found more useful results.

Comment: After a bit research & try, I decided to use https://github.com/themesberg/flowbite-svelte , which contains a `sidebar` component https://flowbite-svelte.com/sidebars , it fits my needs well for now.  It's pretty new, but pretty good from my experience so far.